# Unable to send data to characteristic

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am able to get notified on the app when a remote device change the characteristic value, but when the app update the value back, the remote device won't see it.

So ,I know my characteristic is valid, i also know that **other apps are able to write back to that characteristic (The actual device prints it)**

So problem is of course *in the app*.

Whats more interesting is that every characteristic has **handles** , which have each its own UUID.

**iOS will only let me see my characteristic UUID, no access to its handles, although there are 2 handles for each characteristic with different UUID'S**

Anyway , here I get the callback and try to write back :

```
 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    print("UPDATE FROM:" , characteristic) //good!
    sendData(data: "check")  //not good
       if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == characteristicUUID {
         if let str = NSString(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
         {
            print("BLE:GOT:",str )
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "Bluetooth"), object: str)
         }
      }
}
```

and writing with :

```
  func sendData(data:String)
    {
        if(peripheral != nil)
        {
             //happens for sure
            var bytesData = [UInt8](data.utf8)
            let writeData = NSData (bytes: &bytesData, length: bytesData.count)
             peripheral.writeValue(writeData as Data, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
        }
    }
```

and listing my characteristics ( which prints 1 UUID - thats true we have only 1, but it has 2 handles with different UUID)

```
  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        for charateristic in service.characteristics!
        {
               print("Found CHARACTERISTIC:",charateristic as CBCharacteristic)
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check what properities are set for your characteristic. If `CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite` is set then write with a response can be executed. If only `CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse` is set then you can not execute `writeValue` with `type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse` set.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure I get you. How you check/set this ? I am not sure if you read my question entirely but I did said that other apps are able to write to that same device

Comment: If you don't have access to the firmware or documentation on BLE device side, simply try to change CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse to CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse. If works, that's it. In order to change you need access to the firmware.

Comment: Sure ;-) Take a look on a difference between these as well as on difference between notification and indication. If notification or write without response is used there's no guaranties by BLE protocol design that data will be transferred. Unfortunately if you don't have access to the device side you can not change it, so you have to use it as is.