# Q:iOS characters convert to gbk encoding ,then convert to hex, then to data

Tags: ios, objective-c, character-encoding, hex

In my project with `BLE` develop.

I have to write hex data to `peripheral`,
but now I have a chinese string:

```
NSString *originStr = @"PJ1";
```

But the demo is that:

```
Byte b = 0X01;  // ER: 4552   PJ1：504A31CED2B0AEC1CEC2EDB6F9
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&b length:sizeof(b)];
[self.currPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:self.characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

Now my problem is how to convert my `@"PJ1"` to the `data` in demo.

Comment: Check `CFStringEncodings` (I guess that's `kCFStringEncodingGBK_95`?), and convert directly your `originStr` into `NSData` with `dataUsingEncoding:` no need to use `Byte`.

Comment: @Larme befor your answer I use `NSString *dataStr = writeStr;
        
        NSStringEncoding enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000);
        
        NSData *myData = [dataStr dataUsingEncoding:enc];` I use this to concert , and I get the data:`<xxxxxx>`, but I use the `self.currPeripheral writeValue: `  , it shows no use.

Comment: And it doesn't work?

Comment: It shows the convert is correct, but the `writeValue` function seems no use.

Comment: You mean that `NSString *dataStr = writeStr; NSStringEncoding enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingG‌​B_18030_2000);  [self.currPeripheral writeValue:myData forCharacteristic:self.characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];` doesn't work? Could you define "no use" How do you know it doesn't work`
?

Comment: @Larme `NSString *dataStr = writeStr; NSStringEncoding enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingG‌​B_18030_2000); NSData *myData = [dataStr dataUsingEncoding:enc];`  is okay, but `[self.currPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:self.characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];` seems did not write into the `peripheral`

Comment: `writeValue:data` => `writeValue:myData` (typo issue)? Also, since you use `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse`, did you get an error in the appropriate delegate method?

Comment: @Larme there is two error:`2016-09-21 17:19:07.160 AuroraBuddha[645:138186] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
2016-09-21 17:19:07.162 AuroraBuddha[645:138186] _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)`  but I don't know if this affect me.

Comment: Is `peripheral:didWriteValueForCharacteristic:error:` called?

Comment: @Larme ohh! I print the error use:`
         NSLog(@"setBlockOnDidWriteValueForCharacteristicAtChannel characteristic:%@ and new value:%@ if error:%@",characteristic.UUID, characteristic.value, error);`   and the result is `2016-09-21 17:42:40.997 AuroraBuddha[665:149188] setBlockOnDidWriteValueForCharacteristicAtChannel characteristic:FFF6 and new value:<504a31b6 f9> if error:Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=3 "Writing is not permitted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted.}`, so the 2 error before is does not matter, this is the real affect ours.

Comment: "Writing is not permitted." It clearly states that you can't do anything ! You may need to do another action in order to the peripheral allow you to write on it, but clearly, it's another issue, where the doc of the peripheral may be a good help. Or could it be that in fact you don't want to write on characteristic `FFF6`...

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your patient for me, may I follow you in twitter and facebook? thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Larme's hint,and I use this function to get `data`:

```
NSString *dataStr = writeStr;
NSStringEncoding enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingG‌​‌​B_18030_2000); NSData *myData = [dataStr dataUsingEncoding:enc];
```

And I use the below to write info to `development board`:

```
[self.currPeripheral writeValue:data forCharacteristic:self.characteristic type:CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite];
```

Please Attention: the `type` is not the question's demo: `CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse` but the type:`CBCharacteristicPropertyWrite`. 
Or it will cause the error:

`Error Domain=CBATTErrorDomain Code=3 "Writing is not permitted." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Writing is not permitted.}` . And I also thanks Larme's hint again.

Comment: Note that there is more info on "what should be used in `type` parameter" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603104/unable-to-send-data-to-characteristic